# Receiving TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable at random in Python3

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm writing a simple program in Python that iterates through various API JSON links, and compares values from each of the data sources. As I cycle through one of the JSON files, I call a function that calls a different JSON file based off of one of the values of the initial JSON file.

Here is my Python code:

```
import requests
import json
import urllib.request as request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import time

# THINGS
'''
international API: https://arsonwarehouse.com/api/v1/foreign-stock
domestic API: https://api.torn.com/market/  ?selections=itemmarket&key=KEY
personal API: https://api.torn.com/user/2519609?selections=money&key=KEY
'''

capacity = 21
moneyOverride = False
totalCost: int
totalIncome: int

#Takes in the cost per item, multiplies by capacity, returns true if it's affordable
def checkAfford(costPer):
    global totalCost
    totalCost = capacity * costPer
    if totalCost < money:
        return True
    else:
        return False

#Puts together the API link with the ID number and calls pullJSON()
def checkDomestic(id):
    jsonPULL = pullJSON(f"https://api.torn.com/market/{id}?selections=itemmarket&key=YET")
    if jsonPULL == None:
        print("error")
    else:
        return jsonPULL

#Requests the JSON from the server
def pullJSON(url):
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    webpage = urlopen(req).read()
    with urlopen(req) as response:
        if response.getcode() == 200:
           source = response.read()
           data = json.loads(source)
           return data
        else:
           print('An error occurred while attempting to retrieve data from the API.')

internationalData = pullJSON("https://arsonwarehouse.com/api/v1/foreign-stock")
personalData = pullJSON("https://api.torn.com/user/2519609?selections=money&key=YET")
domesticData = checkDomestic(10)

#Money override
if moneyOverride == False:
    money = personalData.get("money_onhand")
else: 
    money = 1000000000000000

print("onhand:", money)

i = 0 

length = len(internationalData["items"])
print(length)

for x in internationalData["items"]:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ident = x["item_id"]
    domPrice = x["price"]
    print("DOMESTIC:          ID:", ident, " at price:", domPrice)
    domestic = checkDomestic(ident).get("itemmarket")[1]
    inPrice = domestic["cost"]
    if inPrice == None:
        print("error", domestic["ID"])
    location = x["country"]
    print("INTERNATIONAL:     ID:", ident, " at price:", inPrice, "location: ", location)

print("end")
```

This code won't inherently work — I removed my API key from the links. However, I can show what the example JSON looks like.

This is what `checkDomestic()` pulls from:

```
{
"itemmarket": [
{
"ID": 101242786,
"cost": 17898,
"quantity": 1
},
{
"ID": 101242784,
"cost": 17898,
"quantity": 1
}
]
}
```

And this is what `internationalData` looks like:

```
{
"items": [
{
"item_id": 4,
"country": "South Africa",
"price": 750,
"stock": 247,
"reported_at": "2020-06-03T11:47:56Z"
},
{
"item_id": 8,
"country": "Mexico",
"price": 4200,
"stock": 59,
"reported_at": "2020-06-03T11:45:21Z"
}
]
}
```

I've searched around for an answer, but most questions have to do with the `.sort()` method. I should also mention that this happens at random—sometimes in the first 10 iterations, but never at the end, so it's not an out of range error. The JSON structures stay the same across.

A somewhat related question: I've completed this project before in Golang, and I noticed that in Go it finishes much, much, much faster than in Python. Is there some kind of redundancy that's making it take so long? I'm aware of the `time.sleep()` function I have in there-it was to make sure that it's not something with overcalling the API.

Any advice would be massively helpful!